# MUI Data Grid Pro - Persistence of column: widths, visibility, swap

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-persist

I have implemented persistence for the data-grid-pro by storing all needed data for column visibility, column pinned, column swapping, column widths, and column filters in redux and redux-persist.

When the user logs back in all the data stored in redux-persist re-hydrates the store and loads the data-grid-pro how the user left it.

All is working good except if you have an "getAction" column. The api comes back as "undefined" within it.

```
{
field: "actions",
type: "actions",
flex: 0.1,
headerName: "Actions",
getActions: ({ id }) => {
const isInEditMode = apiRef.current?.getRowMode(id) === "edit"; <-- apiRef is "undefined"

if (isInEditMode) {return [...]}

...
}
```

Also, in order for me to persist the table data I needed to store the column definition in state so, I could update it with the new values etc.

```
const columnConfig = [{field: id}...]
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnConfig)
```

But with a little experimenting I guess we cannot store the column definitions with in state so, that begs the question, how can I persist the column data? what is the proper way to persist so that I still can use actions in my table?